# eclipse on LXDE can't run system explorer (file manager)

Tags: eclipse, file-manager

I've installed eclipe on Lubuntu (LXDE). And I can't launch file manager to select any file or directory (for example to change package's location).

By default eclipse has

> Window->Preferences->General->Workspace->"Command for launching system explorer"

set to

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"${selected_resource_uri}" string:""
```

But on LXDE there is no interface `org.freedesktop.FileManager1`.
This interface is implmented in the following environments:

```
Nautilus 3.4 and later.
Dolphin 15.08 and later
```

But on Lubuntu file manager is `PCManFM` which doesn't implement `org.freedesktop.FileManager1`.

I've change this setting to `pcman ${selected_resource_uri}` but it just run `pcmanfm` as standalone file manager without feedback with eclipse.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved using:

```
xdg-open "${selected_resource_parent_loc}"
```

PS: make sure Eclipse does not trunk the starting `x` and does not add invisible elements at the end (it seems incredible, but it did to me... it removed the x and added a U+202C charater, a POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING... probably because I copy/pasted from this answer for setting it to another machine... I don't know)

[Source](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-9.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. It also spawn pcman as standalone file manager without feedback with eclipse.

Comment: `without feedback with eclipse` what does it means? It doesn't open the correct folder?

Comment: Feedback - i mean that you choose desired file or directory and "submit" it to application (to eclipse). How can i do this in pcman ? It is just plain file manager.

Comment: Ok, but can you open `PcManFM` with the target directory from inside Eclipse with `xdg-open "${selected_resource_parent_loc}"`?

Comment: Yes, it spawns `PcManFM` with a directory. But not with "target" , but with "parent of target" . If you want "target" directory - use `xdg-open "${selected_resource_loc}"` instead.
And again - it's meaningless, cause it's impossible to "submit back" to `eclipse` anything from `PcManFM`

Comment: `selected_resource_loc` is the file... not the directory. If you don't like `PCmanFM`, install `Nautilus` or some other file browser. Make sure desktop is always managed by `PCManFM`

Comment: `selected_resource_loc` can be both file and directory..... When you change Location for project in "File->Properties"  the `selected_resource_loc` is the directory of project. And `PCmanFM` opens with this directory.

Comment: Of course, since the resource is a directory. But you usually wants to show a file in the file manager in the parent directory. If you use `selected_resource_loc` with a file, it opens it instead of showing it in `PcManFM`.

Comment: Anyway, you can drag and drop files from `PcManFM` inside the "Package Explorer" view if opened, and add files or folders to your project.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't drag and drop anything from `PcManFM` to "Location" parameter in property window for a project.

Comment: @DmitryPerfilyev: try `Nautilus`: https://askubuntu.com/a/155906/156176